# Hold Button On Red5Phone

Tags: linux, red5, sip, asterisk

I have configured Red5Phone on Red5 Server. I am able to connect to Asterisk Server its working fine. I have used Flex as a client.  Red5  and Asterisk are on the same server.

Now i want a implement a hold button, can any oen please guide me, i am new to asterisk.
How do i begin , do i directly need to call any asterisk function  or red5phone already has that function.  please help me out
Thank You very much .!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Red5(Phone) but you can put calls on hold in Asterisk using the call parking feature. The details are configured in features.conf, but by default, press # to initiate a transfer, then type 700 to park. Asterisk will announce the parking extension between 701 and 720, and you can then hang up. By dialing that announced extension from any phone, you can resume the call later.